# MySQL SELECT user-defined var AS alias WHERE user-defined var is equal to?

Tags: mysql, variables, user-defined

I use a user-defined variable in MySQL to group zip codes. Now I only want to select results with column `rownum` equal to 1. How to select by `rownum` in WHERE clause by alias `rownum`?

Following query gives me the desired results ..

```
SET @row := 0;
SELECT  
  (CASE WHEN @plz <> user.plz THEN @row := @row +1 ELSE @row END) AS rownum, @plz:= user.plz, uid
             
FROM 
  (SELECT @row := 0) AS var,
  user
```

Results:

```
rownum    plz    uid 
1         2378   92014
1         2378   87323
2         6766   91344
2         6766   90342
3         9999   34353
```

Now, I only want to select by specific `rownum`. How to select by alias `rownum`?

```
SELECT  
     (CASE WHEN @plz <> user.plz THEN @row := @row +1 ELSE @row END) AS rownum, @plz:= user.plz, uid
                     
   FROM 
     (SELECT @row := 0) AS var,
     user 
        
   WHERE rownum=1
```

does not work, why? How to select data by alias `rownum` only?

Comment: Use your query as subquery. Apply WHERE in outer query.

Comment: Pay attention! Your query does not contain ORDER BY clause so the query output is indefinite (and it may alter in any moment). Add `ORDER BY user.plz`.

Comment: Why does it not work in the inner query, could you explain?

Comment: Output rowset is calculated AFTER applying WHERE conditions. So you cannot even refer to the output alias in WHERE. You may try to move the condition from WHERE to HAVING - but I don't know does the output will be correct.

Comment: I have tested - moving the condition to HAVING gives incorrect output. Non-applicable.

Comment: What you are trying to do might not even need your MySQL @ variable attempts.  Can you please explain the context of what you are looking for, simple English.  From my interpretation, you have a game with players... Each player in their own zip code, and you are trying to compare to the specific user's zip code.  Do you only want one other player's zip code that is other than the user?  Please EDIT your existing post and add that clarification.  You might just need a select distinct / min() by zip codes other than the user... but again EDIT your post, don't answer in comment.

Comment: With outer query it works, thanks!